# This code when its work not modifying the data into sheet sales and repc only modify for sheet rep

Tags: excel, vba

In this code I'm trying to modify entered data but when im saving its only modifyed sheet rep and others no

```
 Sub ModifySales()
 Dim X As Long
 Dim xx As Long
 Dim fwr As Integer
 Dim fwo As Integer
 Dim Lastrow As Long
  
 lastrow = Rep.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
 fwr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Rep.Range("C7:C"& lastrow), Me.CbInvStore.Value, 
 Rep.Range("F7:F"& lastrow), Me.TbInvNo.Value)
 
  lastrow = Sales.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
 fwrs = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sales.Range("C7:C"& lastrow), Me.TbInvNo.Value)
 
 lastrow = Repc.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
 fwrc = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Repc.Range("B9:B"& lastrow), 
 Me.CbInvStore.Value, Repc.Range("D9:D"& lastrow), Me.TbInvNo.Value)
 fwo = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 ' no of items

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error GoTo 1
```

'========================================================================

```
   With Rep
   .Select
   .Unprotect ("000")
     AutoFilterMode = False
     .Range("$C$6:$Z$6").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=Me.CbInvStore.Value
     .Range("$C$6:$Z$6").AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:=Me.TbInvNo.Value

      lastrow = .Range("F"& Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range("$C$6:$Z$6").AutoFilter

   If fwo = fwr Then
    X = lastrow - fwr
    xx = lastrow - 1
   ElseIf fwo > fwr Then
    d = fwo - fwr
    X = lastrow - fwr
    xx = lastrow + d - 1
    .Range(Cells(lastrow, "c"), Cells(xx, "c")).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ElseIf fwo < fwr Then
    X = lastrow - fwr
    xx = X + fwo - 1
    Y = xx + 1
   z = lastrow - 1
   .Range(Cells(Y, "c"), Cells(z, "c")).Select
     Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Else
     MsgBox "There is somthing wrong. will be exit ", vbCritical, "Inventory Program  "
     End If

     Me.TbDate.Text = Format(Me.TbDate.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy")

   .Range(Rep.Cells(X, "B"), Rep.Cells(xx, "B")) = Me.comDepartment.Value   'Department
    .Range(Rep.Cells(X, "C"), Rep.Cells(xx, "C")) = Me.CbInvStore.Value   'inv_store
     .Range(Rep.Cells(X, "D"), Rep.Cells(xx, "D")) = Me.CbPayment.Value  'pay_method
      .Range(Rep.Cells(X, "E"), Rep.Cells(xx, "E")) = Me.Lbl_typ.Caption   'inv_type
     .Range(Rep.Cells(X, "F"), Rep.Cells(xx, "F")) = Format(Me.TbInvNo.Value, "00000")  'inv 
     no
       .Range(Rep.Cells(X, "G"), Rep.Cells(xx, "G")) = Me.TbDate.Value    'date
     .Range(Rep.Cells(X, "H"), Rep.Cells(xx, "H")) = Me.CbCustomerName.Value   'customer
   .Cells(X, "I") = Me.TbTotalNetPrice.Value   'balance
     .Range(Rep.Cells(X, "T"), Rep.Cells(xx, "T")) = Users.Range("aw6").Value   'users

       If Me.CbInvStore.Value = Data.Range("BF7") Then
    .Cells(X, "Z") = Me.TbTotalNetPrice.Value   'balance
    End If

      If Me.CbInvStore.Value = Data.Range("BF8") Then
    .Cells(X, "Y") = Me.TbTotalNetPrice.Value   'balance
      End If


       Inv.Unprotect ("000")
   Inv.Range("B9:M500").ClearContents
     Inv.Range("B8:M" & 8 + fwo).Cells.Value = Me.ListBox1.List
  .Range(.Cells(X, "J"), .Cells(xx, "S")) = Inv.Range("B9:K" & 8 + fwo).Value 'all product
    .Range(.Cells(X, "W"), .Cells(xx, "X")) = Inv.Range("L9:M" & 8 + fwo).Value 'all product

     .Protect Password:=("000")
     End With
```

'==============================================================================

```
       With Sales
   .Select
     .Unprotect ("000")
    AutoFilterMode = False
     .Range("$C$6:$Z$6").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=Me.TbInvNo.Value

        lastrow = .Range("C"& Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
         .Range("$C$6:$Z$6").AutoFilter

       If fwo = fwrs Then
       X = lastrow - fwrs
       xx = lastrow - 1
      ElseIf fwo > fwrs Then
       d = fwo - fwrs
    X = lastrow - fwrs
        xx = lastrow + d - 1
     .Range(Cells(lastrow, "c"), Cells(xx, "c")).Select
       Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
         ElseIf fwo < fwrs Then
       X = lastrow - fwrs
      xx = X + fwo - 1
         Y = xx + 1
        z = lastrow - 1
       .Range(Cells(Y, "c"), Cells(z, "c")).Select
       Selection.EntireRow.Delete
      Else
          MsgBox "There is somthing wrong. will be exit ", vbCritical, "Inventory Program  "
       End If

        Me.TbDate.Text = Format(Me.TbDate.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy")

     .Range(Sales.Cells(X, "B"), Sales.Cells(xx, "B")) = Me.comDepartment.Value   'Department
      .Range(Sales.Cells(X, "C"), Sales.Cells(xx, "C")) = Format(Me.TbInvNo.Value, "00000")  
   'inv no
      .Range(Sales.Cells(X, "D"), Sales.Cells(xx, "D")) = Me.TbDate.Value     'date
      .Cells(X, "O") = Me.TbTotalNetPrice.Value   'balance
    .Range(Sales.Cells(X, "P"), Sales.Cells(xx, "P")) = Me.CbPayment.Value 'pay_method
    .Range(Sales.Cells(X, "Q"), Sales.Cells(xx, "Q")) = Me.CbCustomerName.Value   'customer
     .Range(Sales.Cells(X, "R"), Sales.Cells(xx, "R")) = Users.Range("aw6").Value   'users


    Inv.Unprotect ("000")
     Inv.Range("B9:M500").ClearContents
     Inv.Range("B8:M" & 8 + fwo).Cells.Value = Me.ListBox1.List
    .Range(.Cells(X, "E"), .Cells(xx, "N")) = Inv.Range("B9:K" & 8 + fwo).Value 'all product
     .Range(.Cells(X, "U"), .Cells(xx, "V")) = Inv.Range("L9:M" & 8 + fwo).Value 'all product

     .Protect Password:=("000")
       End With
```

'===========================================================

```
       With Repc
      .Select
      .Unprotect ("000")
       AutoFilterMode = False
       .Range("$B$8:$P$8").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Me.CbInvStore.Value
      .Range("$B$8:$P$8").AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=Me.TbInvNo.Value

      ss = .Range("f"& Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      .Range("$d$8:$r$8").AutoFilter

     .Cells(ss, "F").Value = Me.CbCustomerName.Value  'customer
      .Cells(ss, "B").Value = Me.CbInvStore.Value  'inv store
     .Cells(ss, "C").Value = Me.TbDate.Value  'date
     .Cells(ss, "K").Value = Me.CbPayment.Value

    .Cells(ss, "O").Value = Me.CbMrName.Value  'mr
      .Cells(ss, "P").Value = Users.Range("aw6").Value  'user

      'CASE RETURN=====================
   If Me.CbInvStore.Value = Data.Range("BF9") Or Me.CbInvStore.Value = Data.Range("BF10") Then
       .Cells(ss, "I") = Me.TbTotalNetPrice.Value    'balance repcus
    Else
   .Cells(ss, "G") = Me.TbTotalNetPrice.Value   'balance repcus
    End If

      If Me.CbPayment.Value = "Cash" Then
     .Cells(ss, "H") = Me.TbTotalNetPrice.Value   'balance repcus
      Else
       End If

        .Protect Password:=("000")
     End With


  If Me.CbInvStore.Value = Data.Range("BF11") Or Me.CbInvStore.Value = Data.Range("BF12") Then

       With Repc
         .Unprotect ("000")
           .Range(.Cells(ss, "G"), .Cells(ss, "P")).ClearContents
        .Cells(ss, "F") = Me.CbCustomerName.Value & " " & Data.[bb3]  'customer repcus offer
         .Protect Password:=("000")
       End With
       End If


        '======== recall inv ========
       Me.Btn_invs.Value = Me.CbInvStore.Value
       Me.Btn_invn.Value = Me.TbInvNo.Value
       CmdRecallInv_Click
         '============================
        sort_rep_customer

         If Me.CreditBox.Value = True Then   'CbPayment = "Credit"
          Call Credit
            End If

       confir = MsgBox(" Change successfully Saved", vbInformation, "Inventory Program")

           1 Application.ScreenUpdating = True


        End Sub
```

Comment: You are using the variables Sales, Rep and Repc. They are not declared anywhere. How are they defined? - And finally: what is your question?

Comment: All of these (Sales و Rep و Repc.) are sheets name

Comment: How do you declare them? Like `Dim Sales As Worksheet`? And again: what is you question?

Comment: if I exchange to this code it will work well but I don't want to make limits like till 80000                                                                                    
 fwr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Rep.Range("C7:C80000"), Me.CbInvStore.Value, Rep.Range("F7:F80000"), Me.TbInvNo.Value)
  fwrs = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sales.Range("C7:C80000"), Me.TbInvNo.Value)
  fwrc = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Repc.Range("B9:B30000"), Me.CbInvStore.Value, Repc.Range("D9:D30000"), Me.TbInvNo.Value)
  fwo = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 ' no of items

Comment: @Black cat
 the concrete values for fwr ( column c (Sales and Purchase) and column F (Invoice Number)    the concrete values for fwrs (Sheet Sales) column C invoice number    and the concrete values for fwrc ( column B (Sales and Purchase) and column F (Invoice Number)  and fwo = listbox for userform